# How do I invite coworkers to my presentation.

Tags: communication, email

I am an Intern this summer and am required to give poster presentation along with all the other interns open to the office in a few weeks as part of my internship.I am significantly younger than all the other interns being as I am still in high school where the other interns are graduated or near graduated college,so I am trying to take the most professional approach. The whole office will notified of the other interns and my presentation in a couple of weeks. I wanted to personally invite a few of my coworkers both on the same project as me(who know me) and some who are outside of my organisation that my manager recommend I invite. What is the most appropriate way for me to invite them? Is it fine for to just say "I would appreciate if you attended"? Or is there a better way to phrase it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about a proposed direct interpersonal interaction or an e-mail invitation (through Exchange or whatever)?

Comment: I am sending them an email invitation through Exchange

Comment: "I am giving my first presentation ever. Feel yourselves invited and give me some support :)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a "Meeting Request" in Exchange that has in the body something like the following:

> As part of my internship here, I'm giving a presentation about some of
>   the things I learned here. I'll be discussing X, Y, and Z. I would
>   appreciate it if you came.

The idea here is that it is more than just a "Please show up" request that the person may or may not know what it is. At the same time, it is useful to make sure you explicitly put in the request or ask in the body so that it isn't a question of, "Well, now what?" after someone has read it.